# Uploading a file to SharePoint using C# is wiping the metadata

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I need to upload versions of a file to SharePoint and set various metadata values. I created code to do this where I would upload the file, set the metadata fields then upload the other versions of the file.

This all worked fine in my development environment and a couple of client environments but in one when I upload the second version of the file the metadata is wiped. Subsequent file uploads fail due to missing metadata errors.

I tried many different permutations of code to try and get the file to upload and retain the metadata and the only way I have found to get all the files upload and set the metadata is:

```
ListItem listItem = null;

using (StreamReader srRev = new StreamReader(revision.EStore.Path + revision.EStoreId.Replace('+', '\\')))
{
  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File newFile = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(new FileCreationInformation() { Url = folder + filename, ContentStream = srRev.BaseStream });
  clientContext.Load(newFile);
  listItem = newFile.ListItemAllFields;
  clientContext.Load(listItem);
  clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
  srRev.Close();
}

listItem.RefreshLoad();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (string name in settings.Keys)
  listItem[name] = settings[name];
listItem.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (string filepath in files)
{
  using (StreamReader srRev = new StreamReader(filepath)
  {
    FileSaveBinaryInformation fsbi = new FileSaveBinaryInformation() { ContentStream = srRev.BaseStream };
    itemFile.SaveBinary(fsbi);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    listItem.RefreshLoad();
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    foreach (string name in settings.Keys)
      listItem[name] = settings[name];
    listItem.Update();
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    srRev.Close();
  }
}
```

However, this results in double the amount of versions I want in SharePoint. I get a version for each file uploaded and then a version 8kb bigger with the metadata added.
[image of item's version history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOsaY.png)

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong or the setting in SharePoint that could be causing this?